# How can I upload an image in a custom form and save the result in a custom database table?

Tags: 8, forms, files

I have a custom form and I want to store the values in a custom database table. After submitting the form, the `first_name` and `email_address` fields are successfully saved to the database, but image field (`file` below) is not saving correctly. When I load the values from the database, the `file` field shows an empty array. Furthermore, checking the database table shows a value of NULL stored in the field.

**How do I upload an image through a custom form and save the resulting file id in the database?**

Below is my custom form class.

```
namespace Drupal\my_block_example\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;

class WorkForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_block_example_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['first_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('First Name:'),
      '#pattern' => '[A-Za-z]+',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['email_address'] = array(
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => $this->t('Email:'),
      '#pattern' => '[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['file'] = array(
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#name' => 'file',
      '#fid'  => 'fid',
      '#title' => t('Logo'),
      '#description' => t('Upload a logo.'),
      '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    );

    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $conn = Database::getConnection();
    $file = $form_state->getValue('file');

    if (!empty($file)) {
      $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($file);
      $file->setPermanent();
      $file->save();
    }

    $conn->insert('employ')->fields(array(
      'first_name' => $form_state->getValue('first_name'),
      'email' => $form_state->getValue('email_address'),
    ))->execute();

    $form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 2]);
  }
}
```

Comment: i just want to know how i can upload an image through custom form in a block plugin, i have mentioned my code above, i don't know what is issue in this code, i am not able to upload an image,after submission of form, Null value save of image field in database

Comment: I think this issue has enough information to be answered. It looks like the file is created correctly in the `submitForm` method, but the file id is never stored with the rest of the form data.